# jQuery show() and hide() not working on IE8 and IE9

Tags: jquery

I have the following code it's not working on IE8 and IE9. It works fine on Firefox and Chrome though. How can I make this work on IE?

I am using jQuery version **1.9.1**.

**HTML**

```
<p class="showhide">
    <h4 id="Show">Expand</h4> 
    <h4 id="Hide">Collapse</h4> 
</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Hide").hide();

    $("#Show").click(function(e) {
        $("div.moreinfo").slideDown(200);
        $("div.plus").hide().removeClass("closed");;
        $("div.minus").show().addClass("opened");
        $("#Show").html("Expand All").addClass("expanded");     
        $("#Show").hide();
        $("#Hide").show();

        e.preventDefault();              
    });

    $("#Hide").click(function(e) {  
        $("div.moreinfo").slideUp(200);
        $("div.plus").show().addClass("closed");    ;
        $("div.minus").hide().removeClass("opened");    
        $(".message").html("Collapse All");  
        $("#Show").show();
        $("#Hide").hide();

        e.preventDefault();          
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using version jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: I would do e.preventDefault() first, and have you tried .toggle() ?

Comment: @AdamRoof Why would `preventDefault()` be needed? There's no default action for clicking on `<h4>`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what action he's preventing with that.  Is that necessary?  Show and Hide are h4 tags.

Comment: Is your code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @Barmar - true, didn't look at that, just assumed he was clicking on Button server control and needed to preventDefault

Comment: Yes its inside document ready

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4acm3eu3/1/

Comment: Theres also "slideToggle()" that looks to be doing what you are doing manually. My arrows are png's that I have change to DownIndicator or RightIndicator http://jsfiddle.net/s624y0bu/   again just assuming what your div.plus and div.minus are and trying to be helpful